# MySQL update to change all instances containing -html to .html

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to update a bunch of records in my database that store a slug in an article table. I mistakenly set the slugs to end in "-html" rather than ".html" and I need a query that will fix this.

I don't really understand how to use variables, so I'm hoping someone here can help.

Would someone please write for me a SQL query that's something like:

```
UPDATE table
SET table.slug = '%.html%'
WHERE table.slug LIKE '%-html%'
```

Obviously, that's not correct, but I don't know the correct way to write it.

Comment: The `'%'` is a wildcard character (matches zero or any number of characters) in the context of a `LIKE` operator.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a quick-and-dirty example using [`REPLACE()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_replace)

```
UPDATE table
SET slug = REPLACE(slug, '-html', '.html')
WHERE slug LIKE '%-html'
```

Just be warned that this will replace **any** occurrence of `-html`, even if it's not at the end of the string.

A more comprehensive approach might be

```
UPDATE table    
SET slug = CONCAT(TRIM(TRAILING '-html' FROM slug), '.html')
WHERE slug LIKE '%-html'
```

Comment: +1. Note that the second form has a similar issue as the first, in removing multiple occurrences of '-html' from the end; it will remove repeating occurrences of that string from the end.

Comment: @spencer7593 Seems unlikely that the strings would end in `-html-html-html` but you make a good point nonetheless

Comment: I agree about it being unlikely. But in the more general case, it's definitely something to be aware of, just like we need to be aware of the same kind of thing with REPLACE.

Answer (score 2):

Mine will only replace the last '-html', and append '.html'by `CONCAT`:

```
UPDATE table
SET slug = CONCAT(SUBSTRING(slug, 1, LENGTH(slug) - 5), '.html')
WHERE slug LIKE '%-html'
```

Comment: Great answer. MySQL's 1-based string indexing makes my head hurt though :)

Comment: @Phil ah ha, thank you, Phil! I always get a head hurt with that like you, too!:)

Comment: +1. This meets the specified requirements... removing a single occurrence of a trailing `'-html'` and replacing it with `'.html'`. Nice job.

Comment: @spencer7593 Thanks! I hope this could be what sanitycheck wants.

Answer (score 1):

You have to make use of replace command.

```
UPDATE Table Tablename
SET MyColumnname = REPLACE(MyColumnname, '-html', '.html')
WHERE MyColumnname LIKE '%-html%'
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd make use the the `TRIM` and `CONCAT` functions:

Something like this:

```
UPDATE `table` t
   SET t.slug = CONCAT(TRIM(TRAILING '-html' FROM t.slug),'.html')
 WHERE t.slug LIKE '%-html'
```

Note that the `TRIM(TRAILING '-html'` will remove all occurrences of that specified string from the end of the column value, so if I had (for example) a column value of `'foo-html-bar-html-html'`, that would return `'foo-html-bar'`.

I use the `CONCAT` function to append '.html'.

The WHERE clause guarantees that I will only be modifying rows that have a column value ending in `'-html'`.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html

Comment: Looks similar somehow ;)

Comment: Yes, it does look similar; that's the nature of the SQL string functions. When I started my answer, your answer just had the REPLACE.